# BRISQUE Implementation for OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, opencv

I used BRISQUE in Matlab before and it worked fine so I decided to use it again in C#.
However, BRISQUE in OpenCvSharp (the same goes for Python and C++ as well) requires a SVM model data and range data saves - as seen in the [documentation](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_docs/html/30b85ef9-83c4-b39f-b5e3-565c3df0b152.htm).

```cs
public static QualityBRISQUE Create(string modelFilePath, string rangeFilePath)
public static QualityBRISQUE Create(SVM model, Mat range)
```

According to MATLAB's [documentation](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/brisque.html?s_tid=srchtitle); < brisque compare A to a default model computed from images of natural scenes with similar distortions >. Do such save files exist in openCV or must I make them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found them, on the *opencv_contrib* GitHub page.

You can find both YML files (the model and the range files) [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/quality/samples).